# Can't get the index type right on typescript instance method

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I'm trying to call a method depending on some arguments, but I can't get it to compile.

the errors I'm getting:

```
test/unit/account-client/AccountGateway.spec.ts:59:10 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '(<T = any>(params: GetRequestParams) => Promise<HttpResponse<T>>) | (<T = any>(params: PutRequestParams) => Promise<HttpResponse<T>>) | (<T = any>(params: PutRequestParams) => Promise<...>)' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.

59     when(x[httpVerb](anything())).thenResolve(success);
            ~~~~~~~~~~~

test/unit/account-client/AccountGateway.spec.ts:59:47 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ statusCode: number; headers: {}; body: { id: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'.

59     when(x[httpVerb](anything())).thenResolve(success);
                                                 ~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors.
```

code first attempt:

```js
function whenAccountApiRequestSucceeds(httpVerb: 'get' | 'post' | 'patch') {
  const success = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {},
    body: account,
  };
  when(httpClient[httpVerb](anything())).thenResolve(success);
}
```

Second attempt, the one that generate the errors above:

```js
function whenAccountApiRequestSucceeds(httpVerb: 'get' | 'post' | 'patch') {
  const success = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {},
    body: account,
  };
  const x = {
    get: httpClient.get,
    post: httpClient.post,
    patch: httpClient.patch,
  };
  when(x[httpVerb](anything())).thenResolve(success);
}
```

third attempt using `Pick` and `keyof`, `httpClient` is an instance of the class `HttpClient`:

```js
 function whenAccountApiRequestSucceeds(
    httpVerb: Pick<keyof HttpClient, 'get' | 'post' | 'patch'>,
  ) {
    const success = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {},
      body: account,
    };

    when(httpClient[httpVerb](anything())).thenResolve(success);
  }
```

this time I got even lint errors:

- `Type 'Pick<keyof HttpClient, "get" | "post" | "patch">' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)`
- `Type '"get" | "post" | "patch"' does not satisfy the constraint 'number | "toString" | charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" |"replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | "substring" | "toLowerCase" | ... 31 more ... | "trimRight"'.'.ts(2344)´

---

Just for the record, this work's without errors:

```js
function whenAccountApiRequestSucceeds(_httpVerb: 'get' | 'post' | 'patch') {
  const success = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {},
    body: account,
  };

  when(httpClient['get'](anything())).thenResolve(success);
  when(httpClient['post'](anything())).thenResolve(success);
  when(httpClient['patch'](anything())).thenResolve(success);
}
```

`when()`, `anything()`, and `.thenResolve()` are [ts-mockito](https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito) functions

What I need to do to get this dynamic method call working?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to constitute a [mcve] which demonstrates your issue when dropped as-is into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W44x1W), or failing that, consider providing a link to a configured web IDE project that demonstrates the issue.  This will allow people who want to answer to start working on a solution instead of spending time working on reproducing the problem in the first place.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is the closest to correct, so let's break down that error:

> This expression is not callable.
>
> Each member of the union type '(<T = any>(params: GetRequestParams) => Promise<HttpResponse>) | (<T = any>(params: PutRequestParams) => Promise<HttpResponse>) | (<T = any>(params: PutRequestParams) => Promise<...>)' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.

Your `httpVerb` is a union type.  It could be any of `'get' | 'post' | 'patch'`.  You get a function based on this name with `httpClient[httpVerb]`.  That function could be `get()` or `post()` or `patch()`.

These functions have different arguments -- either `GetRequestParams` or `PutRequestParams`.  Since we don't know which one it is, we need to ensure that any arguments that we pass are assignable to **all** members of the union.  The error says that this is not possible.

```
declare const f: ((v: number) => void) | ((v: string) => void)
```

As a basic example, if you have a variable `f` which could take either a `string` or a `number`, you cannot possibly call it in a type-safe way.  There is no argument that satisfies both branches.

I don't know where these types are coming from so I don't know what the specific incompatibility is between `GetRequestParams` and `PutRequestParams`.  It could be just the method name?  So I can't give you the greatest answer here without all the information.

It might help to use a generic:

```
function whenAccountApiRequestSucceeds<T extends 'get' | 'post' | 'patch'>(httpVerb: T) {
```

Comment: @jcalz I often recognize what packages people are using by the type names and I was expecting this to be node http or something, but I actually googled `PutRequestParams` and I get nothing!  So this is probably some custom type where it's very possible that the types themselves are bad.